# Error: Non-hexadecimal digit found

Tags: python, nft, brownie

I seem to be running the following error when I try to run this script:  ,

```
from brownie import AdvancedCollectible, accounts, network, config

def main():
    dev = accounts.add(config['wallets']['from_key'])
    print(dev)
```

My brownie-config.yaml:

```
# exclude SafeMath when calculating test coverage
# https://eth-brownie.readthedocs.io/en/v1.10.3/config.html#exclude_paths
reports:
  exclude_contracts:
    - SafeMath
dependencies:
  - smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.0.2
  - OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@3.4.0
compiler:
  solc:
    remappings:
      - '@chainlink=smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.0.2'
      - '@openzeppelin=OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@3.4.0'
dotenv: .env
wallets:
  from_key: ${PRIVATE_KEY}
  from_mnemonic: ${MNEMONIC}
```

The error:

```
brownie run scripts/advanced_collectible/deploy_advanced.py 

Brownie v1.14.3 - Python development framework for Ethereum

NftdemoProject is the active project.

Launching 'ganache-cli --port 8545 --gasLimit 12000000 --accounts 10 --hardfork istanbul --mnemonic brownie'...

Running 'scripts/advanced_collectible/deploy_advanced.py::main'...
  File "brownie/_cli/run.py", line 49, in main
    return_value, frame = run(
  File "brownie/project/scripts.py", line 103, in run
    return_value = f_locals[method_name](*args, **kwargs)
  File "./scripts/advanced_collectible/deploy_advanced.py", line 4, in main
    dev = accounts.add(config['wallets']['from_key'])
  File "brownie/network/account.py", line 132, in add
    w3account = web3.eth.account.from_key(private_key)
  File "eth_utils/decorators.py", line 18, in _wrapper
    return self.method(obj, *args, **kwargs)
  File "eth_account/account.py", line 246, in from_key
    key = self._parsePrivateKey(private_key)
  File "eth_utils/decorators.py", line 18, in _wrapper
    return self.method(obj, *args, **kwargs)
  File "eth_account/account.py", line 694, in _parsePrivateKey
    return self._keys.PrivateKey(HexBytes(key))
  File "hexbytes/main.py", line 23, in __new__
    bytesval = to_bytes(val)
  File "hexbytes/_utils.py", line 17, in to_bytes
    return hexstr_to_bytes(val)
  File "hexbytes/_utils.py", line 50, in hexstr_to_bytes
    return binascii.unhexlify(ascii_hex)
Error: Non-hexadecimal digit found
```

I made sure I have my keys set in my .env file as `export PRIVATE_KEY='0x..."`, so why is it not able to pull the variable from it or am I missing some step here? Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: could you run `echo $PRIVATE_KEY` and verify that the private key is correct with the `0x` appended? And could you add your `brownie-config.yaml` file to the question?

Comment: Updated with my `brownie-config.yaml` Just ran `echo $PRIVATE_KEY` but it didn't return anything, I did notice that my .env file seems to be getting read as plaintext by visualstudio... could that be the problem?

Comment: Run `source .env` in your shell. Or add `dotenv: .env` to your brownie config

Comment: I already had `dotenv: .env` in my brownie config (interesting why that didn't work), so I tried to run `source .env` per your advice, and that seems to now return the correct key from my .env file when i run `echo $PRIVATE_KEY`. Double checked it to make sure i have it appended correctly, but still getting the non-hexadecimal digit error.

Comment: Does it have the 0x at the front?

Comment: yea it has the 0x at the front

Comment: Hmm.... I’m at a loss. Perhaps you can try the steps with a different key? Maybe there is a space in your export string?

Comment: My issue was that I had OX not 0x somehow, go figure!

Answer (score 1):

I have the same error on my Windows system. When i hardcoded my private key in `brownie-config.yaml` `from_key: 0x...` everything works fine. So, i think the problem in python part, when it tries to get variable. Also, trying to get value in console using `echo $Env:PRIVATE_KEY` works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered the same error, what should fix it is the python package python-dotenv. Once you install it python should be able to read those .env files.